# Accessing MVC server side variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, drupal

I'm moving one of our web applications from Drupal to an ASP.net MVC Web Application.

One of the Drupal functions gets some data from a web service and converts it to a JS Array, as follows:

```
foreach ($xml_result->JobList->JobDetail as $job_detail) {
//  dsm((array)$job_detail); 
$open_job_details[] = array("east"=>(string)$job_detail->Easting,"north"=>(string)$job_detail->Northing, "duedate"=>(string)$job_detail->openDate);
}
//dsm($open_job_details); 
$open_jobs_data = json_encode($open_job_details);
drupal_add_js(array('open_jobs' => array('open_newjobs' => $open_jobs_data)), 'setting');
```

In the Javascript file, it is accessed using;

```
var openJobsData = JSON.parse(Drupal.settings.open_jobs.open_newjobs);
```

Is there a simple way to access a server side variable in the JS file in .NET? I can call the web service and get the relevant data from the XML file but not sure how to access it in the JS file.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use Strongly Typed view to create cshtml page

- if you want to access JSON object

  View1.cshtml
  @model mvcApplication1.Models.model1
              @{
                  var serializer = new 
                      System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                  serializer.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
                  var jsonModel = serializer.Serialize(Model);
              }
         var   JsonData = @Html.Raw(jsonModel); // declare a javascript variable and use it
- if  you want to access server variable at cshtml page
  just use `@` to access server-side variables
  after getting the value you can use  javascript variable in another js file

  Declare your javascript variable outside
  $(document).ready(function()
          {}

  or before using the variable

***you can use that variable in Javascript file.***