# Web API securisation javascript client

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4, razor-pages

I have an ASP .Net core razor pages application which is configured to use IdentityServer 4 for authentication with windows provider. This razor pages web app is allowed to contact a .Net core Web API ( separate project ) which manage all business logic.

Razor pages contain Javascript that execute AJAX request to this Web API. Currently i'm using razor page controller as proxy so the javascript call the razor page controller which call the Web API. Everything is working fine but I would like to call  the Web API directly from the javascript and to secure this part.

Inside of my razor pages web app, I haves access to user claims and can manage authorizations to check if user is allowed to contact Web API for an update for example. How can I secure my Web API and allow direct Javascript call ?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I haven't looked at IS4 directy but calling a API controller should be the same as a calling a Razor Page (with changing the path). Are you setting the validation token?

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned in question you are using `IdentityServer4` as authorization provider

you can use the following way.

[Adding a javascript client](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/6_javascript_client.html)

**Template for Javascript files** [oidc-client JavaScript files](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/tree/release/dist)

**Html**

```
 <html> <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <title></title> </head> <body>
     <button id="login">Login</button>
     <button id="api">Call API</button>
     <button id="logout">Logout</button>

     <pre id="results"></pre>

     <script src="oidc-client.js"></script>
     <script src="app.js"></script> </body> </html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function log() {
    document.getElementById('results').innerText = '';

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments, function (msg) {
        if (msg instanceof Error) {
            msg = "Error: " + msg.message;
        }
        else if (typeof msg !== 'string') {
            msg = JSON.stringify(msg, null, 2);
        }
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML += msg + '\r\n';
    });
}
```

use `UserManager`Class to connect to IdentityServer4

```
 var config = {
        authority: "http://localhost:5000",
        client_id: "js",
        redirect_uri: "http://localhost:5003/callback.html",
        response_type: "code",
        scope:"openid profile api1",
        post_logout_redirect_uri : "http://localhost:5003/index.html",
    };
   var mgr = new Oidc.UserManager(config);
```

**At WebApi Part**:
add a new client for javascript client.

```
// JavaScript Client
new Client
{
    ClientId = "js",
    ClientName = "JavaScript Client",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
    RequirePkce = true,
    RequireClientSecret = false,

    RedirectUris =           { "http://localhost:5003/callback.html" },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5003/index.html" },
    AllowedCorsOrigins =     { "http://localhost:5003" },

    AllowedScopes =
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        "api1"
    }
}
```

for more reference about [how to add  new client](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/clients.html)

**Update for:**
**Ajax call to Identity Server and get Token**

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://localhost:5000/connect/token",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "a19f4ba3-b5aa-c61a-8078-c1a6ee39d5df"
  },
  "data": {
    "grant_type": "password",
    "username": "Test1@test.com",
    "password": "123456",
    "client_id": "client",
    "client_secret": "client123",
    "scope": "scope1"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Problem with this approach is the redirection, when user goes to the application there is a razor page that is rendered from the server only if the user is authenticated ( this is the Index.cshtml ). In this page, I have an AJAX call to web api when document is ready and other javascript call depending of users actions. Is there a way to authenticate the user via javascript call without redirection ? I want to stay on main page as it is just a part of it that the javascript is rendering.

Comment: Do you mean to say your user is authenticated at index.cshtml?
you can take authorization token at javascript and pass it to your Ajax call. no need to redirection

Comment: Yes exactly, when the page is rendered it means that the user is authenticated. How can I pass the authorization token from Ajax call?

Comment: from a server-side variable, you can take the token to javascript variable

`var cleintSideTokenVariable= @Html.Raw(tokenvariableServerSide); // declare a javascript variable` for reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/53446977/7262120

Comment: Ok, but how do I pass this token to the web API ? In ajax request header ? Can you please me an example ?

Comment: you can directly hit Identity server and get the token via ajax call, updating answer...

Comment: Problem is that I use Windows provider inside identity server, Users doesn't have to enter credentials so I can't use password grant type. And if  I use code grant type, redirect URI is mandatory for token endpoint. Maybe the best solution is to simply use windows authentication as it is an intranet application. The idea was to reuse identity server for other applications but I don't know how to make it works for this app..

Comment: Is this helpful https://damienbod.com/2018/04/15/supporting-both-local-and-windows-authentication-in-asp-net-core-mvc-using-identityserver4/